# how can i add the "publish_pages" permission to a test_user of my facebook app?

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, facebook-test-users

I have a facebook app and its now in live_mode .
i have the mange_pages permission and need the publish_pages permission to be able to post to the pages https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_pages.
for this purpose i need to show the reviewer of my app how the user expirence will look like .
my app is ready to simulate the expirence but i cant add the permission "publish_pages" to any of my apps test users https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users.

i tried to do it from the developers platfrom and thow the graph-api.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/app/accounts/test-users

Answer (score 0):

You can not access all permissions any more using app roles, when they are not reviewed yet, but your app is already in live mode. It still works for many, but for some of the more important ones, Facebook closed that “loophole”.

You will need to put your app back in dev mode, or if that is not possible because it is already in production use, create a test app version of it, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: My app is in dev mode. That is why I don't understand why I can't see all permissions.